# ¿La etiqueta H1 puede estar en una posición baja de un artículo sin que pierda su calidad?

Tags: html, seo

Tengo un articulo que tiene un encabezado (o titulo), un parrafo y una imagen. EL problema es que, segun mi diseño, el orden de esos elementos no es el tradicional. Mi imagen esta arriba, mi parrafo al medio y mi encabezado abajo. Asi es el diseño, asi se ve bien. Primero quiero preguntar si el h1 puede ir abajo. Segundo: Necesito meter el h1 en un contenedor (es necesario por un tema de estilos)..¿puedo meter al h1 en un footer del article, sin afectar el posicionamiento? dejo mi codigo:

```
<article>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p>...</p>
  <footer><h1>HOLA</h1></footer>
</article>
```

O tambien podria remplazar el footer por un header, pero iria en la ultima posicion, igual.

Answer (score 5):

El posicionamiento en los motores de búsqueda es algo que cambia permanentemente (finalmente depende de lo que decidan hacer Google, Bing y etc, más allá de las reglas de la W3C) y no hay una respuesta definitiva al respecto, salvo que alguien que trabaje ahí lo indique, de lo contrario es aprendizaje por prueba y error.

Normalmente se necesita o se recomienda tener no más y no menos de un H1, sin importar la posición en el documento, [aunque en la especificación se acepta más de un H1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/the-h1-h2-h3-h4-h5-and-h6-elements.html#rank).

---

En [este enlace de la W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/headings-and-sections.html#headings-and-sections) se puede ver que este código es correcto a pesar de tener los encabezados (h4, h2, h6 y h1) en orden atípico:

```
<body>
 <h4>Apples</h4>
 <p>Apples are fruit.</p>
 <section>
  <h2>Taste</h2>
  <p>They taste lovely.</p>
  <h6>Sweet</h6>
  <p>Red apples are sweeter than green ones.</p>
  <h1>Color</h1>
  <p>Apples come in various colors.</p>
 </section>
</body>
```

---

Por último, y como bien dice Google, lo que importa es hacer sitios web que puedan leer, disfrutar y entender los usuarios, incluyendo aquellos que tienen discapacidad, los motores de búsqueda se encargan de posicionarlo rápidamente si muchos usuarios lo visitan y si tienes enlaces en otras partes, entre otras tantas razones. En los `<meta>` generalmente se incluye mucha información relevante para los motores de búsqueda, aunque según algunas personas que trabajan en Google y con quienes he tenido la oportunidad de conversar: «Google es tan inteligente que sus algoritmos deciden qué indexar y cómo hacerlo, muchas veces independientemente de lo que hagas o indiques con tus tags en el código»

Answer (score 0):

El  o  son contenedores normales, tu los puedes posicionarlos a tu gusto, pero estan hechos para crear un estandar de la web y que tu pagina tenga buen posicionamiento.

asi que si podrias ponerlo como cualquieras de las dos mientras cumpla la función de la etiqueta, pero podrias dejarlo como footer, haciendo referencia a la parte de abajo del documento.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML_sections_and_outlines#Defining_sections

segun el seccionamiento, cada bloque necesita su titulo asi que dejarlo asi seria lo mas correcto supongo